# How to determine the commit id using the new deployment yml file?

Tags: git, fortrabbit

I am using the new deployment fortrabbit.yml file to trigger post commit hooks. Before, the git webcall hooks (http://fortrabbit.com/docs/in-depth/git-hooks/webcall) provided me with information about the actual commit. How can I now (http://fortrabbit.com/docs/in-depth/deployment-file) access this information? I would like to know the commit ID (e.g. 40cede3910db6ba0140993ae0d33376ff5df7483). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webcall hooks continue to exist in the new deployment **fortrabbit.yml** file. Simply use the post-deploy hook and set an url, like so:

```
post-deploy:


    # alternatively/additionally an URL can be specified which is called after
    #   deployment
    url: http://domain.tld/callback

    # token which will be send as request header `X-Frbit-Token` to verify that
    #   the request originated from this post-deploy call (defaults to "unset")
    token: your-own-token
```

In your callback, you receive the commit ID: 
http://fortrabbit.com/docs/in-depth/git-hooks/webcall#the-callback-url

Comment: So $_POST['before'] and $_POST['after'] are sent to the callback also in the new system? Thanks! :)